# How to make this php script dynamic?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I currently have a script I'm making in PHP. Here is what I'm trying to do - I have a few different locations with different times and dates, like an RSVP.

There are only so many spots (or slots as called here) for each "location" the #1 has a maximum of 20 slots. The first part of the script I've included here gets the sum of all the reservations in the table for that location. The other part is when the form gets posted it compares the current amount of slots already reserved, the max slots, and how many they are trying to reserve.

There is a dropdown on the page where they can select how many slots they want to reserve. So say there are 15 slots already reserved, they try to reserve 6, but as the max is 20 it shouldn't pass and be sent to another page. This all works fine, but as the rest is dynamic, I don't want to have to keep adding, and to keep it cleaner each time a new location is added if you get what I mean? I was thinking some type of foreach but I'm not sure how I'd get it to work for this. There is a table called locations which has the max slots and all the information. Each one has an id which relates to a table which reservations are reserved. I need to get this done in the next couple hours if anyone could help, or have any ideas I'd be very appreciative! Thanks

```
$result1 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM `1`");
$row1 = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$slots1 = $row1['value_sum'];
if(!isset($row1['value_sum'])) {
    $slots1 = '0';
}

$result2 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM `2`");
$row2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$slots2 = $row2['value_sum'];
if(!isset($row2['value_sum'])) {
    $slots2 = '0';
}

$result3 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM `3`");
$row3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$slots3 = $row3['value_sum'];
if(!isset($row3['value_sum'])) {
    $slots3 = '0';
}

$result4 = $db->query("SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM `4`");
$row4 = $result4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$slots4 = $row4['value_sum'];
if(!isset($row4['value_sum'])) {
    $slots4 = '0';
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $passed = false;
    if ($id == '1'){
        $query = "SELECT maxslots FROM locations WHERE id = 1";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $slotamount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $slots_all = $slots1 + $_POST['slots'];
        if ($slots_all > $slotamount) {
            header("Location:index.php?toomany=1");
        } else {
            $passed = true;
        }
    }

    if ($id == '2'){
        $query = "SELECT maxslots FROM locations WHERE id = 2";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $slotamount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $slots_all = $slots2 + $_POST['slots'];
        if ($slots_all > $slotamount) {
            header("Location:index.php?toomany=2");
        } else {
            $passed = true;
        }
    }

    if ($id == '3'){
        $query = "SELECT maxslots FROM locations WHERE id = 3";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $slotamount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $slots_all = $slots3 + $_POST['slots'];
        if ($slots_all > $slotamount) {
            header("Location:index.php?toomany=3");
        } else {
            $passed = true;
        }
    }

    if ($id == '4'){
        $query = "SELECT maxslots FROM locations WHERE id = 4";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $slotamount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $slots_all = $slots4 + $_POST['slots'];
        if ($slots_all > $slotamount) {
            header("Location:index.php?toomany=4");
        } else {
            $passed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). [Check if it will be on-topic there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first though.

Comment: You have written: "SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM `1`". Is there a table with name 1 ??

Comment: Reply fast.. you have only two hours. I will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function getSlotSum($id) {
    $result = $db->query("SELECT SUM(SLOTS) AS value_sum FROM $id");
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $slots = $row['value_sum'];
    if(!isset($row['value_sum'])) {
       $slots = '0';
    }    
    return $slots;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $passed = false;
    $query = "SELECT maxslots FROM locations WHERE id = $id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $slotamount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $slots_all = getSlotSum($id) + $_POST['slots'];
    if ($slots_all > $slotamount) {
        header("Location:index.php?toomany=$id");
    } else {
        $passed = true;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In reply to your other question yes there is a table named "1", as well as "2", "3", etc and more as they are added. For the first part I need it to display in a table on the same page which is why I called them slots1, slots2, etc. I then echo them inside of the page. The one you have seems like it'd only display one and not all of them? Thanks.